# Merging multiple directories into one

Tags: directory, rsync

I have a below folder structure:

```
->fol1
  ->file1
  ->file2
->fol2
  ->file2
  ->file3
->fol3
  ->fol1
  ->fol4
```

What I want is that I should be able to merge these 3 directories( or even more than 3) and put it into another folder which is at the same level at fol1, fol2 and fol3. The final directory should look like:

```
->new_dir
  ->file1
  ->file2
  ->file3
  ->file4
```

I tried using rsync but find out that it won't work with three directories. It is guaranteed that files with same name in different directories have exact same content.

Please suggest some way so that I can accomplish my task.

Thank You!

Comment: `--include=file.*  --exclude=*  */.  new_dir/` did not work?

Comment: Is this a full command? Please give full command if it is not.